# How to stitch two images using related keypoints?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv, python

So here is my code, I see that I am able to stitch the image by drawing the matches, but match lines are overwritten on images, I just wanted to have a plain stitched image, Is there any way to do that?
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img1=cv2.imread('11.png')
img2=cv2.imread('12.png')
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2,des2=sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1,des2, k=2)
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75*n.distance:
        good.append([m])

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,flags=2)
cv2.imshow('i',img3)
```

Here are the two images and here is the output:

Result (with lines in it I do not want):

[image: Result]

First one:

[image: First image to be stitched]

Second one:

[image: Seocnd image to be stitched]

What I wanted to get:

[image: Image I actually want to create]

---

Instead of obtaining an image like this with matches, I wanted to obtain the image which is stitched through the matches but not displaying those matches.